# Fixed point $u(x) = F(u)(x)$ properties

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fixed-points

Let $F:H^1(\Omega) \to H^1(\Omega)$  be some map. Suppose we have a function $u$ such that for some $x \in \Omega$, $$u(x) = F(u)(x).$$

From this, I think it follows that 
$$u(x) = F(F(...F(u))..)(x) = F^{(n)}(u)(x)$$
(that's composition $n$ times) for any $n$.

This seems a bit strange to me. Can we say anything about $F$ or $u$ if this happens for $x \in D \subset \Omega$ with $D$ not a null set?

Comment: $F(F(u))(x) \ne F(F(u)(x))$

Comment: @daw Yes,  since $F$ is defined on $H^1$ and not $\mathbb{R}$. But I don't use this, and $u(x) = F^{(n)}(u)(x)$ still is true, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

This conclusion is not valid. Take $\Omega =\mathbb R$, $F$ defined by
$(Fu)(x) = u(x+1)$.

Take $u$ which is zero outside of $(-1,2)$ and one in $[0,1]$. Set $x=0$.
Then 
$$
u(0)=1, \ F(u)(0) = 1, \ F(F(u))(0)=0.
$$

Comment: Right. I guess it#s only true if $F(u)(x) = f(u(x))$.